Private IP addresses CIDR block
I want to have 1000 private IP addresses in my VPC. Can I use the IP address range 192.168.0.0/22 for achieving this?
NETMASK: 255.255.252.0
CIDR BASE IP: 192.168.0.0
BROADCAST IP: 192.168.3.255
COUNT: 1,024
FIRST USABLE IP: 192.168.0.1
LAST USABLE IP: 192.168.3.254

The subnet mask /22 means that the first 22 bits of the IP address are network bits, leaving 32 - 22 = 10 bits for host addresses. The subnet consists of 1024 IP addresses (2^10), but not all of them are usable because some addresses are reserved for network address, broadcast address. Is my calculation correct and can I use the 192.168.0.0/22 for my VPC?

Yes your calculation is correct. This is indeed how subnet masks work.

The IP address range referenced in the query is part of Class C IP address range. Is it permissible to utilize a Class C IPv4 address, given that Class C networks allocate 24 bits for the network number and 8 bits for host numbers?

@KM Classes were completely obsolete and deprecated when CIDR became standard practice in the early 1990's. It's weird that we keep teaching people about a concept that's been utterly meaningless for three decades. I don't even have evidence that classes were ever enforced by popular TCP/IP stacks.

The addresses to avoid are 0, 254 and 255.
This gives 1024 - 3 = 1021, which is more than 1000.

You only need to avoid the all-zeroes (network) and all-ones (broadcast addresses) all others, including the .254 and the .0 and .255 addresses inside the range are fine.
